# three.js How to create a cube using BufferGeometry with 6 different textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to create a cube using BufferGeometry with 6 different textures

I have to use BufferGeometry because I want to change shape.
I want to create an element with different textures on the sides.
What is the best way to create a solid?
How do I upload different textures?
Can I create uvs and indices automatically? so that when adding a vertex, the script does the rest.

This is my code:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script>
      (async () => {
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
          75,
          window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
          0.1,
          1000
        );
        camera.position.z = 1;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
        controls.panSpeed = 0.4;

        let itemThickness = 18;
        let itemHeight = 50;
        let itemDepth = 25;
        let itemX = 0;
        let itemY = 0;
        let itemZ = 0;

        var quad_vertices = [itemX,itemY,itemZ,itemX,itemHeight,itemZ,itemDepth,itemHeight,itemZ,itemDepth,itemY,itemZ,
        ];
        var quad_uvs = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0];
        var quad_indices = [0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2];
        var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        var vertices = new Float32Array(quad_vertices);
        
        var uvs = new Float32Array(quad_uvs);
      
        var indices = new Uint32Array(quad_indices);
       
        geometry.setAttribute(
          "position",
          new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3) //ilosc wierzcholkow
        );
        geometry.setAttribute("uv", new THREE.BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));
        geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices, 1));

        // Load the texture asynchronously
        var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var texture = await textureLoader.loadAsync(
          "https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/cat.jpg"
        );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: texture,
        });
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.position.z = -100;

        scene.add(mesh);

        function render() {
          requestAnimationFrame(render);
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
          controls.update();
        }
        render();
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Having `THREE.BoxGeometry()`, you can pass an array of 6 materials into the constructor of `THREE.Mesh()` instead of a single material. This is the easiest way. `new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry(), [material1, material2, material3, material4, material5, material6]);`

Comment: I have to use BufferGeometry the shapes will be more complicated and there will be holes over time

Comment: Have a look at `.groups` of `BufferGeometry`: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups

Comment: I made six separate objects (arrays) but it will improve how you write.

When I do .groups it:
For a cube, I only need 8 vertices and 12 indices? Will it be correct?